# HTML form in Django REST frameWork and RelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the user settings model:

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.UserProfile'  related_name='own_user')
     lookup_user = models.ManyToManyField('userprofile.UserProfile')
```

I have written a custom field:

```
class SettingKeywordsField(serializers.RelatedField):
     def to_native(self, value):
         eturn { str(value.pk): value.username }
```

and using in serializer:

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      lookup_user = SettingKeywordsField(many=True)
      class Meta:
         model = UserSettings
         fields = ('lookup_user')
```

In this situation, lookup_user is not appear in html form tab.

What is wrong in my serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializers.RelatedField` defaults to `read_only=True` ...try:

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lookup_user = SettingKeywordsField(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
        fields = ('lookup_user')
```